# Windows Server 2012 R2 RDs Licensing

Tags: remote-desktop, windows-server-2012-r2, licensing

I just installed the Remote Desktop Service Role on a windows server 2012 R2. Now I want to license this service, so more than two users can access the service simultaneously. That for I need a RD Licensing server.

My question now is, can I run both of those services on the same server?

Regards,
Brutlallama

Answer (score -2, accepted):

It is possible to install both RDS licensing and RDS role on the same server. Two or more users can easily access the services simultaneously without any problem. By default trial period for the RDS licensing server is 120 days.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I will try it an give a feedback!

Comment: You should edit this answer and provide specifics. You also only answered one of the author's questions.

Comment: Looks like asker has edited his original question since my reply. I answered exactly what he asked so don't understand the reason to downvote.

Comment: @AzfarUllahKhan Id did work properly, thank you for your help!